# Add template Reference (sidewaffle project)

Tags: sidewaffle

I'm using Visual Studio Premium 2012 and installed sidewaffle. Working through examples to create a template using the falling video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z33jOo75CH4&list=UUwEinBp3Mx1UuAR52pzRcNw
I cannot see 'Add template Reference (Sidewaffle project)' on the add menu when I right click the project. Do you know how I get this option to show? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't get side waffle to work, I found it over complicated, I used templify instead. http://opensource.endjin.com/templify/ this works really well for creating a multiple project template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get side waffle to work, I found it over complicated, I used templify instead. http://opensource.endjin.com/templify this works really well for creating a multiple project template.

Comment: I'm sorry that you were unable to get SideWaffle to work. Thank you for letting us know what you used to get your template to work. We'll check out templify and see what we can do to improve the process for multiple project templates.